# Filter pipe isn't working correctly angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

The problem I am having is when the page loads in and the API call is made the ngfor loop doesn't show all of the values, but when I type something in the search box to filter it works fine, what I want it to do is return all of the values when the search filter isn't applied when the page initially loads.

```js
/*Filter Pipe*/
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, filterString: string, propName: string): any {
    if (value === null && value.length < 1 || filterString === '') {
      return value;
      /*This value isn't returning when fiter isn't applied on load*/
    }
    const resultArray = [];
    for (const item of value) {
      filterString = filterString.toLowerCase();
      if (item[propName].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString) >= 0) {
          resultArray.push(item);

    }
  }
    return resultArray;
 }
}
/*Conponent*/
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getStopData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.stations = data;
      }
    );
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline md-form form-sm active-pink-2 mt-2">
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3 w-75" name="search" [(ngModel)]="search" type="text"
    placeholder="Search train stations" aria-label="Search">
  <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</form>
<!-- Card -->
<div *ngFor="let station of stations?.results?.objStation | filter:search:'StationDesc'">
<mdb-card class="m-1">
  <!--Card content-->
  <mdb-card-body>
    <!--Title-->
    <mdb-card-title>
      <h4>{{station.StationDesc}} Train Station</h4>
      <hr/>
    </mdb-card-title>

    <img class="col-6 panel-realtime" src="assets/img/icon_view.png" (click)="getStation(station.StationCode); basicModal.show()"
      mdbWavesEffect/>
    <img class="col-6 panel-remove" src="assets/img/thumbnail_icon_map.png" (click)="getMaps(station.StationDesc); mapsModal.show()" mdbWavesEffect/>

  </mdb-card-body>
</mdb-card>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Angular recommends not using pipes for filtering (https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe). For this kind of behaviour, I'd recommend using Observables. Using reactive forms, you can subscribe to the `valueChanges` Observable of your input and use that to filter your incoming data.

Comment: Does your component use OnPush strategy?

Comment: No all it does is makes an api call to my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming, you are not initializing search variable, as you have not mentioned above. If you are not initializing **search** variable in your component.ts, then on page load.
The value of search variable will be **undefined** not **''**

**Solution 1:**

```
export class Component implements OnInit{
  search: string;

  constructor() {
   this.search = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getStopData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.stations = data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, filterString: string, propName: string): any {
    if (value === null && value.length < 1 || (filterString === '' || filterString === undefined)) {
      return value;
      /*This value isn't returning when fiter isn't applied on load*/
    }
    const resultArray = [];
    for (const item of value) {
      filterString = filterString.toLowerCase();
      if (item[propName].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString) >= 0) {
          resultArray.push(item);

    }
  }
    return resultArray;
 }
}
```

Comment: The second solution was the one that worked I have initialized the search var as a string in the component but I didn't have undefined in the pipe thank you very much for your assistance .

Comment: No problem at all :)